# jQuery plugin activation bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, bug-tracking

I'm having some trouble identifying a bug on the website I'm developing. To be more specific, I'm using [jPages](http://luis-almeida.github.com/jPages/) twice on the same page.

The first instance of the plugin is used as a navigation through the website as it is a one page website. A
nd the second instance is used to browse through a bunch of products rather than scrolling.

You can find the website I'm building here :  .

I'll also paste all the JavaScript, because I have no idea for now where the bug is and why is behaving like that :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var default_cluster_options = {
    environment             : "Development",
    local_storage_key       : "Cluster",
    plugin_navigation_class : ".navigation",
    plugin_wrapper_id       : "content-wrapper",
    headings                : ['.heading-first h1', '.heading-second h1'],
    input_types             : ['input', 'textarea'],
    info_iqns_class         : ".iqn",
    preview_iqn_class       : ".preview",
    limits                  : [ { min: 1224, items: 8 }, { min: 954, items: 6 }, { min: 624, items: 4 }, { min: 0, items: 2 } ],
    shop_local_storage_key  : "Shop",
};

var default_plugin_options = {
    containerID : "",
    first       : false,
    previous    : false,
    next        : false,
    last        : false,
    startPage   : 1,
    perPage     : 1,
    midRange    : 6,
    startRange  : 1,
    endRange    : 1,
    keyBrowse   : false,
    scrollBrowse: false,
    pause       : 0,
    clickStop   : true,
    delay       : 50,
    direction   : "auto",
    animation   : "fadeIn",
    links       : "title",
    fallback    : 1000,
    minHeight   : true,
    callback    : function(pages, items) {}
};

var Cluster = function(cluster_options, plugin_options) {

    var self = this;

    this.options = $.extend({}, default_cluster_options, cluster_options);

    this.plugin_options = $.extend({}, default_plugin_options, plugin_options);

    this.environment = this.options.environment;

    this.data_key = this.options.local_storage_key;

    this.shop_data_key = this.options.shop_local_storage_key;

    this.plugin_navigation_class = this.options.plugin_navigation_class;

    this.plugin_wrapper_id = this.options.plugin_wrapper_id;

    this.headings = this.options.headings;

    this.input_types = this.options.input_types;

    this.viewport = $(window);

    this.body = $('body');

    this.viewport_width = this.viewport.width();

    this.viewport_height = this.viewport.height();

    this.info_iqns_class = this.body.find(this.options.info_iqns_class);

    this.preview_iqn_class = this.body.find(this.options.preview_iqn_class);

    this.limits = this.options.limits;

    this.current_shop_page = this.options.current_shop_page;

    this.total_shop_pages = this.options.total_shop_pages;

    this.initiate_cluster(self.plugin_navigation_class, {
        containerID : self.plugin_wrapper_id,
        startPage : +(self.get_local_storage_data(self.data_key) || 1),
        callback : function(pages){
            self.set_local_storage_data(self.data_key, pages.current);
        }
    });

    this.inititate_shop();

    this.initiate_shop_touch_events();

};

Cluster.prototype.set_environment = function() {
    if(this.environment == "Development") {
        less.env = "development";
        less.watch();
    }
};

Cluster.prototype.set_local_storage_data = function(data_key, data_val) {
    return localStorage.setItem(data_key, data_val);
};

Cluster.prototype.get_local_storage_data = function(data_key) {
    return localStorage.getItem(data_key);
};

Cluster.prototype.initiate_scalable_text = function() {
    for(var i in this.headings) {
        $(this.headings[i]).fitText(1.6);
    }
};

Cluster.prototype.initiate_placeholder_support = function() {
    for(var i in this.input_types) {
        $(this.input_types[i]).placeholder();
    }
};

Cluster.prototype.initiate_iqn_selected_class = function() {
    if(this.viewport_width < 980) {
        $(this.info_iqns_class).each(function(index, element) {
            var iqn = $(element).parent();
            $(iqn).on('click', function() {
                if($(iqn).hasClass('selected')) {
                    $(iqn).removeClass('selected');
                } else {
                    $(iqn).addClass('selected');
                }
            });
        });
    }
};

Cluster.prototype.initiate_preview_action = function() {
    $(this.preview_iqn_class).each(function(index, element) {
        var data = $(element).attr('data-image-link');
        $(element).on('click', function(ev) {
            $.lightbox(data, {
                'modal'         : true,
                'autoresize'    : true
            });
            ev.preventDefault();
        });
    });
};

Cluster.prototype.initiate_plugin = function(plugin_navigation, plugin_options) {
    var options = $.extend({}, this.plugin_options, plugin_options);
    return $(plugin_navigation).jPages(options);
};

Cluster.prototype.initiate_shop_touch_events = function() {
    var self = this;
    return $("#shop-items-wrapper").hammer({prevent_default: true, drag_min_distance: Math.round(this.viewport_width * 0.1)}).bind("drag", function(ev) {
        var data = JSON.parse(self.get_local_storage_data(self.shop_data_key));
        if (ev.direction == "left") {
            var next_page = parseInt(data.current_page + 1);
            if(next_page > 0 && next_page <= data.total_pages) {
                $(".shop-items-navigation").jPages(next_page);
            }
        }
        if(ev.direction == "right") {
            var prev_page = parseInt(data.current_page - 1);
            if(prev_page > 0 && prev_page <= data.total_pages) {
                $(".shop-items-navigation").jPages(prev_page);
            }
        }
    });
}

Cluster.prototype.inititate_shop = function() {
    var self = this;
    for(var i = 0; i < this.limits.length; i++) {
        if(this.viewport_width >= this.limits[i].min) {
            this.initiate_plugin('.shop-items-navigation', {
                containerID : "shop-items-wrapper",
                perPage     : self.limits[i].items,
                midRange    : 8,
                animation   : "fadeIn",
                links       : "blank",
                keyBrowse   : true,
                callback    : function(pages) {
                    var data = {
                        current_page : pages.current,
                        total_pages  : pages.count
                    }
                    self.set_local_storage_data(self.shop_data_key, JSON.stringify(data));
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    }
};

Cluster.prototype.initiate_cluster = function(plugin_navigation, plugin_options) {
    this.set_environment();
    this.initiate_scalable_text();
    this.initiate_placeholder_support();
    this.initiate_iqn_selected_class();
    this.initiate_preview_action();
    this.initiate_plugin(plugin_navigation, plugin_options);
};

var cluster = new Cluster();

});
```

And the bug I was talking about, when you are on the **Home** page and navigate to the **Shop** page you will notice the the second instance of the plugin doesn't activate as the items should only be 8 ( if the width of the screen is more than 1224px ) and you should be able to browse through with the keyboard left and right arrows, but you cannot.

But if you are on the **Shop** page, hit refresh and the plugin will now activate after page load.

So, I would like some help with that, tracking the bug, because I'm still learning JavaScript and I'm not very experienced with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [jPages](https://github.com/luis-almeida/jPages/blob/master/js/jPages.js) source file this happens because at *second* plugin initialization plugin can't find `:visible` elements as they are hidden by *first* plugin initialization <sup>(line 60)</sup>:

```
this._items = this._container.children(":visible");
```

To load your shop module with `jPages` plugin you need to initialize that plugin after shop items are shown. To do this you need to modify `callback` value in `initiate_cluster` function:

Lets say that *Shop* page index is `4`:

```
Cluster.prototype.initiate_cluster = function(plugin_navigation, plugin_options) {
    // ... your code
    plugin_options.callback = function( pages ) {
        if( pages.current == 4 ) {
            this.inititate_shop();
        }
    };
    this.initiate_plugin(plugin_navigation, plugin_options);
};
```

And remove `this.inititate_shop();` function call from `Cluster` class constructor.

This should work.

Or you can try to swap plugin calls, but I'm not sure:

```
// first we initiate shop
this.inititate_shop();

// then main site navigation
this.initiate_cluster(self.plugin_navigation_class, {
    containerID : self.plugin_wrapper_id,
    startPage : +(self.get_local_storage_data(self.data_key) || 1),
    callback : function(pages){
        self.set_local_storage_data(self.data_key, pages.current);
    }
});
```

Comment: Regarding the first part, indeed, the Shop page has as index 4. I was doing something similar before, calling scripts based on pages, but I'm not sure if it's safe having so many functions in the callback function of the plugin. Also, what happens if I'm not on the Shop page ? It means that the second instance of the plugin won't be activated. I'll try your solution right now, I'll let you know what happend.

Comment: If you not on Shop page, second plugin initialization will wait until you go to Shop page. And yes, if you at About page Shop page plugin will not be initialized but you don't need at this stage. Also I just trying to swap plugin calls and everything worked so I think second solution I provide is best for you.

Comment: If I swap the plugin calls the touch events won't work properly. If you drag the mouse cursor to left ( or if you have a touch device drag to left ) it will jump to page 2 ( of the first instance of the plugin which corresponds to About page ). I had this problems before with that.

Comment: How about hack with callback?

Comment: Let me upload the first solution test so you can see the behavior :)

Comment: Here it is : http://rolandgroza.com/projects/roland/ ; Uploaded, see the weird behavior, now it doesn't store the last page I was on anymore ( I guess because I'm overwriting the callback function ) and the drag events are behaving like described above, if you drag to left ( because right won't work since you're on the first page ) you jump to the About page ( which shouldn't happen, it should jump to the second page of items ).

Comment: Ok and how about trying to pass callback as in-depended object?`this.initiate_plugin(plugin_navigation, {callback: function(pages){if(pages.current == 4) { self.inititate_shop(); }});`

Comment: It would be the same, it will overwrite the initial callbacks

Comment: Ok, and if you swap and add `initiate_shop_touch_events` before `initiate_cluster`? I.e: `this.inititate_shop(); this.initiate_shop_touch_events(); this.initiate_cluster();`

Comment: Seems like the problem I encounter if I'm calling scripts based on the index, is the drag event. Which behaves as described. Take a look now at the source ( js on the link I provided ). I resolved the other one ( landing on the last visited page ).

Comment: Maybe you need to move `this.initiate_shop_touch_events();` to that callback too? `if(pages.current == 4) {self.inititate_shop(); this.initiate_shop_touch_events();}`